# Laravel connection with postgres doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm just setting up a new Laravel installation with a postgressql server using a role with NO superuser privileges (test). I'm using Manjaro to test and I've installed php 8 and enabled/installed php-pgsql with pgsql and pdo_pgsql extensions uncommented at /etc/php/php.ini

Laravel does seem to detect the table but it can't run migrations. These are the commands I'm using:

php artisan migrate:install (this one works)

php artisan migrate:status (this one doesn't work, it can't find the migrations table)

Also this is my .env (the relevant piece):

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=test
DB_PASSWORD=
```

This is what I get from the test user within laravel:

```
test=> \l
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8         | es_CL.utf8 | es_CL.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8         | es_CL.utf8 | es_CL.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |              |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8         | es_CL.utf8 | es_CL.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |              |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test      | test     | UTF8         | es_CL.utf8 | es_CL.utf8 |
```

Answer (score 0):

For command `migrate:status`, Laravel calls this method in internal class `PostgresGrammar` in namespace `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars`.

```php
/**
 * Compile the query to determine if a table exists.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function compileTableExists()
{
    return "select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ? and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'";
}
```

If you see it select records from `information_schema` which needs proper permissions to work. The **user**, in your case `test`, needs to be the owner of the schema, which is `test` in your case, to get any rows from `information_schema.tables` which are related to your schema.

run this command to change the owner of the schema:

```sql
alter schema `test` owner to `test`;
```

Or the user needs to be a member of a group that owns the schema.

**Note:**
Usage grant is not sufficient. The user does not need to be a superuser. The user can own a table in a schema, but that is not sufficient either.

**Refs:**

- [What permissions are required to return rows from information_schema.schemata?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138116/what-permissions-are-required-to-return-rows-from-information-schema-schemata)
- [PostgresGrammar Implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4b2e3e7317da82dd9f5b88d477abd93444748b43/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L73)

Comment: The owner of the database test is test. That's what \l shows above. When I run migrate I get  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  no existe la relación «migrations»
LINE 1: select "migration" from "migrations" order by "batch" asc, "...
                                ^ (SQL: select "migration" from "migrations" order by "batch" asc, "migration" asc)